# How do I mask an image within HTML img tag?

Tags: html, css, image

So, this is pretty short and simple, but I've found no answers no matter how long I've searched.

How do I simply `mask` and `<img>` in the HTML tag alone.

For example:

```
<img src="img.png" alt="img.png" style="mask:white"/>
```

I can't find online any way for this to work, does anyone have a solution?

EDIT:

TL;DR I want my logo (profile picture) without the white.

Comment: Are you talking about `SVG` mask?

Comment: doesn't svg require you to make a big extensive blob of text though? would there be a way to incorperate it into the `<img>` tag?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do or why. If you have some specific effect you are trying to achieve it might be best to provide an image link of the desired result.

Comment: Look, I just want to key out white. See my profile picture? Imagine that appeared on my website, but the white wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't describe the type of mask, below is  general css masking.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

```
img {
  mask-image: url(mask.svg);
}
```

Where mask.svg is your image mask file.